# Users Bookmarking Regions on a Map

Tags: maps

I'm working on designing an app that involves data visualization of an inventory against a map. Basically, one of the functions a user can engage through the map is the creation of geographic bookmarks or favorited regions that will be stored as clickable links that interface with the map API to return the user to that specific region they were viewing when they created the bookmark.

Is there a terminology for such a function? I feel like calling such a feature a "geographical view", "bookmark", or "favorite" is a bit weird. Has anyone solutioned for this before? I'm representing the function through an icon that's a bookmark with a star on it. Granted, it makes sense to have the function called "My Bookmarks" or something of the like, but I think it's a bit odd pairing that terminology with geography.

Comment: Suggestion: Geo Bookmarks. Also, for the icon you can consider a location pin with a radius around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is "**My Places**".

Google maps uses this term for something similar :

> Organize content relevant to you on the classic Google Maps with **My Places**. Here’s what you’ll find in My Places:
>
> - My Maps: Maps you've created to share information with others. Learn how to create a map.
> - Starred locations: Landmarks, businesses, or addresses that you’ve saved so you can find them easily on the map. Read more about starring locations.
> - Ratings: Businesses you’ve rated and reviews you’ve written.
>
>   - Search history: Locations or directions you’ve searched for or viewed in the past if Search History was turned on. You can pause or turn on Search History from your Search History

Also ArcGIs has the same term for :

> The **My Places** dialog box lets you create and work with a list of your most frequently used or favorite addresses, locations, features, and spatial extents. You can use this dialog box to navigate around to view these places. You can also annotate your map to show their locations and add the places into the route finding dialog boxes as stops and barriers. Adding items to the My Places list makes it easy for you to store your frequently used addresses, gazetteer locations, features, and extents and use them to navigate around maps and globes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a [Placemarks](http://www.designingmapinterfaces.com/patterns/placemarks/) UI Pattern